# Is 3/4 plywood good enough for blocking

Tags: walls, vent, plywood, hood, blocking

I want to hang a vent hood on the wall and this wall has electrical and gas pipe between studs.  It only has enough space for 3/4 plywood blocking.  Is this adequate? Thanks

Comment: You will need a bit more info than that. A picture of your conditions is needed including the hood. That said, most hoods I have set, was able to use just the studs in the walls.

Comment: How will you ensure that the screws you use to attach your vent hood to your 3/4" plywood don't go all the way through it and into the pipes behind?

Comment: @brhans use 3/4" screws? :)

Comment: How much does the range hood weigh?  How is it meant to mount to the wall?  Does it really require blocking, or does it have some sort of adjustable rails or brackets that can accommodate various stud locations -something like a TV wall mount?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Floor assemblies can use 5/8" plywood for joists 16" oc.  Floor assemblies carry people, pianos, fridges, etc.  3/4" plywood will certainly hold a range hood.  You'll need to use enough fasteners.